# Telerik RadGrid - How do I set the MaxLength for the Insert Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, telerik

I have a radGrid on the page with the "Add New Record" button.  When I click the "Add New Record" button, a textbox appears above each column that allows me to enter values.  I want to limit the number of characters that can be entered in the textbox.  How do I set the MaxLength of those textboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling me exactly what the problem is I don't think. You very-well could try to use the MaxLength property (if it's not a multiline TextBox). But is that really your problem? Or do you already know how you can accomplish this, but you're having trouble getting the control via server-side or client-side code so that you can set the MaxLength property??

If you could provide a code snippet or two and some more details regarding your problem, I'd be better-able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the input and sorry I was not clear but you solved my problem.  I didn't think it could be as simple as putting a MaxLength on the column but that did it.  I thought it was more complicated and I would have to set the MaxLength on the textbox somehow.  Sometimes the most obvious is the most missed.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :-)